# How to add target="blank" to this php code

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a link in code that looks like this:

```
$tlink = JRoute::_( '/terms-and-conditions' );
```

Can somebody help me please, I want to add a target="_blank" attribute to this link... I tried different things I found on web like adding:

```
,array('target' => '_blank')
```

to the JRoute::_() but nothing changes...

Can somebody give me a hand please. Thank you

---

Here is how this link is further used:

```
$terms = array ();
$terms [] = JHTML::_ ( 'select.option', 1, JText::sprintf ( 'I_AGREE', $tlink ), 'value', 'text' );

$lists ['terms'] = GHelper::checkbox ( $terms, 'terms_n_condtions', 'class="inputbox required" size="1"', 'value', 'text', 0 );
```

Comment: If the destination is hard-coded, why you don't just hard code the entire link?

Comment: How are you using `$tlink`? I think `JRoute` only creates the URL, not the whole `a` tag. (Correct me if im wrong)

Comment: Are you trying to put a link in the select option which should open in a new tab?

Comment: Nope, $terms goes into $lists, and $lists is a checkbox "GHelper::checkbox"

Comment: sorry everybody, I found it :) the normal/standard <a href></a> is in the joomla LANGUAGE FILE.. and I can add there normally target="_blank" :) Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

Is it not as simple as,

```
<a target="_blank" href="/<?php echo JRoute::_('/terms-and-conditions'); ?>">LINK</a>
```

**OR** enclosing the link tag in a variable like,

```
$link = "<a target='_blank' href='".JRoute::_('/terms-and-conditions')."'>LINK</a>";

echo $link;  // will give you the markup of the link
```